# how to spi device driver become simple?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

> when i write driver for spi I must care about device-tree, vitual hardware address,irq number... but I cann't need do it with usb driver, i just use APIs without see hardware config. 
> static struct usb_driver pen_driver = 
> { 
> .name = "pen_driver",
> .id_table = pen_table, 
> .probe = pen_probe, 
> .disconnect = pen_disconnect,
> };

> not has .driver = { }; as spi driver.
>
>  It seems that i2c, spi, usb,... is driver that exists in os.

So, Can I write spi driver same usb driver (mid-driver) without care about low-level.

Comment: No, you can't. The answer to it in the hardware architecture and physical layer protocols. It's OS independent.

Comment: For "plug and play" device buses like USB and PCI(e), the host uses ID information provided by the device to determine what sort of device it is. That is baked into the protocols. There is no equivalent for SPI or I2C protocols, so the host needs to be told what sort of device is connected at each SPI CS# line (on an SPI bus) or I2C slave address (on an I2C bus) by other means.